# Expression Blend's default LayoutRoot

Tags: layout, expression-blend, sketchflow

Is there a way to change the default LayoutRoot type in Expression Blend 3? Currently, I'm prototyping in SketchFlow, and I prefer Canvas over the Grid, and it's annoying to change it for every new screen.

Comment: Hate to say it but it looks like there's no way to do it. Even the manual mentions a way that no longer exists (Tool-Options-Projects, uncheck 'Use a grid panel as the default layout for new items'; doesn't exist).

Comment: That's what I figured. Oh well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is answer that will work, but you will need to change the templates:

1. **Back up the contents of the template directory which resides here**:
   %ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Expression\Blend 3\Templates\
2. Find the templates being used in:
   %ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Expression\Blend 3\Templates\(CSharp|VisualBasic)\
3. In that directory there will be 4 relevant templates:
   SketchFlowCompScreen,
   SketchFlowCompScreenSL,
   SketchFlowNavScreen,
   SketchFlowNavScreenSL
4. If you edit the xaml files within these, whenever you create a new screen in SketchFlow the screens will use your changes.

Comment: I'm glad there's a way, but it sucks there isn't a better/cleaner/easier way. Thanks.